# Dynamically updating a stacked bar plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, dynamically-generated

I would like to know how I can dynamically update a stacked bar plot in matplotlib.

This question [Dynamically updating a bar plot in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16249466/dynamically-updating-a-bar-plot-in-matplotlib) describes how it can be done for a normal bar chart, but not a stacked bar chart.

In a normal bar chart the update can be done via `rect.set_height(h)` assuming that `rects = plt.bar(range(N), x, align='center')`

But in a stacked bar chart we also need to set the bottom.

```
p2 = plt.bar(ind, womenMeans, width, color='y',
             bottom=menMeans, yerr=menStd)
```

How can I dynamically set the bottom? Unfortunately it seems that the 'Rectangle' object has no attribute 'set_bottom'. Is there any alternative way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, the `set_bottom()` function you want is `set_y` under `patches` in the return object from `bar`. The minimal example, based on the link you suggest would look like,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def setup_backend(backend='TkAgg'):
    import sys
    del sys.modules['matplotlib.backends']
    del sys.modules['matplotlib.pyplot']
    import matplotlib as mpl
    mpl.use(backend)  # do this before importing pyplot
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    return plt

N = 5
width = 0.35       # the width of the bars: can also be len(x) sequence

def animate():
    # http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Animations
    mu, sigma = 100, 15
    h = mu + sigma * np.random.randn((N*2))
    p1 = plt.bar(np.arange(N), h[:N], width, color='r')
    p2 = plt.bar(np.arange(N), h[N:], width, color='b', bottom=h[:N])
    assert len(p1) == len(p2)
    maxh = 0.
    for i in range(50):
        for rect1, rect2 in zip(p1.patches, p2.patches):
            h = mu + sigma * np.random.randn(2)
            #Keep a record of maximum value of h
            maxh = max(h[0]+h[1],maxh)
            rect1.set_height(h[0])
            rect2.set_y(rect1.get_height())
            rect2.set_height(h[1])
        #Set y limits to maximum value
        ax.set_ylim((0,maxh))
        fig.canvas.draw()

plt = setup_backend()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
win = fig.canvas.manager.window
win.after(10, animate)
plt.show()
```

Note, I change the height generation using random numbers each iteration so the two arrays of patches can be zipped instead (would get a bit messy otherwise).

Comment: That is working very well. Many thanks. Is there also a way to update the axis? When the bars get higher than the axis, then they are no longer shown at the moment.

Comment: You can use `ax.relim()` to update maximum range and then `ax.autoscale_view()` to adjust the axis (where `ax` is the axis handle). You may find animation ends up a bit jerky and it's better to set a constant limit throughout (based on maximum expected from your data). I've changed the example above to use subplots (so you get `ax`) and update the limits only when it gets bigger than the previous maximum value.