# Bar plot animation in Matplotlib (Loop Operation)_New

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to animate the data points which i receive from a DL model.
I have followed the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42056347/animated-barplot-in-python).

I had created my animated plot which satisfies my requirement. 
Kindly see the `picture below`, where it shows `X axes labels Defect & No Defect start to raise from 0 and reach a maximum point`.

I want two conditions to be met, after the animation completed,

> 1. How can I annotate or display a message in the plot after the animation gets completed. (for eg : in my case I want to display maximum value - either defect or No defect in the plot based on the value)
> 2. The picture shows below is for 1 iteration which ran for 100 frames. In the same way, i have another 30 iterations data where each of them should run for 100 frames using `FuncAnimtaion`, which produces animation graph for each iterations and display/annotate the maximum value at the end of iterations. 
>      I can give my 30 iterations one by one and produce results, but how one can achieve in code totally.

**Picture**
[image: at]

**Code**

```html
from matplotlib import animation
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def barlist(n): 
    
    # model detail
    b = n + 1
    c = X_test[0][:b].reshape((-1, b, X_test.shape[2])) # Input to model
    mod = model.predict_on_batch(c) # DL Model which takes input c
    pred = np.argmax(mod, axis=2) # Output a array

    St = np.count_nonzero(pred == 0)
    Rt = np.count_nonzero(pred)
    return [St, Rt] # for every frame St, Rt gets updated & animate plot

fig = plt.figure()
axes = plt.axes()
axes.set_ylim([0, 110])

x = np.arange(0,2)
my_xticks = ['Defect','No Defect']
plt.xticks(x, my_xticks)
barcollection = plt.bar(x,[0, 0], width= 0.3)

n = 100 #Number of frames

def animate(i):
    y = barlist(i)
    for i, b in enumerate(barcollection):
        b.set_height(y[i])
   



anim=animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate,repeat=False,blit=False,frames=n,interval=50)
   
plt.show()
```

Comment: I reopened the question (seems no duplicate anymore), but I honestly have no idea what problem you face here.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest
I am not facing any problem, I am asking 
1) `how can i annotate after completing 100 frames`. (print the highest value, say for example in my graph `Defect`has higher number. So annotate or print Defect is Maximum after completing the 100 frames.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest 
2 : As you can see above in my above code `c = X_test[0]...`
`X_test is of shape (30, 100, 4)`. In the code above I have used only `X_test[0]` which means I used only `1st (100, 4)` and built a animation as per your answer.
I can perform the same animation individually like  input `X_test[1]`  - animate, input `X_test[2]` - animate and so on....Instead I would like to do it in a single shot. Like if i give `X_test`, animate function should take `X_test[0]`,  animate it, print which one is greater, then `X_test[1]` ,  animate it, print which one is greater & so on

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I hope I have clarified my question correctly. If not please let me know.